# WS-Policy X509Token with Supporting Tokens

Tags: cxf, x509certificate, wsse

I have a WSDL that contains WSPolicy, the policy defined uses supporting tokens and with-in supporting tokens it uses X509 Tokens. Below is a snippet of the WSDL having the policy

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
           xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
           xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
           wssutil:Id="MyPolicy">
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
     <wsp:All>
        <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
           <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
              <wsp:Policy>
                 <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
              </wsp:Policy>
           </sp:X509Token>
        </sp:SupportingTokens>
     </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Now when I generate my client (using Apache CXF), consume any web service operation, I don't see the wssec security header getting added to the SOAP header. As a result, the SOAP service throws error as the Policy Validation Interceptor fails.

I have done a lot of search and have not found any sample / example using this kind of policy, supporting tokens have been used along with Assymetric / Symmetric bindings.

Want to know if the policy defined is correct, if yes, then what will be the client code to access this service.

Just to add, when I put below interceptor into the client code, the security header gets added (with a Binary Security Token and Signature), however, the service still fails (with Policy Verification Interceptor)

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor()); 

    Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "myclientkey");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, 
        ClientKeystorePasswordCallback.class.getName());
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "clientKeystore.properties");
    outProps.put(ConfigurationConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
    client.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

Below is the error stack trace

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens
at     org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:86)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:52)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:41)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1638)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1527)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:215)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:638)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
... 2 more
```

Any help will be much appreciated!! I am stuck with this issue since 2 days.

Comment: From what I have figured out till now, this appears to be a WSDL issue. When I try to create a service using the above WS-Policy in my WSDL (with Apache Rampart & Axis2), I get error while deployment. Will debug more into it and post the results

Comment: Which cxf-version do you use?

Comment: CXF version is 3.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Using a BinarySecurityToken as a SupportingToken with no security binding won't work with CXF. You need to specify a security binding in order to sign the request as well.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the reply Colm. Even I thought so, however, can this be done using Apache Rampart configured with Axis2?